# Rails 3, add a link_to to add a product id to a session variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a simple app with a single model of Product with name and price attributes. In addition to the standard scaffolding actions in the index view I would like to add a link_to action 'add_to_cart' that will add a products id to a session variable. So far I have...

index.html.erb

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= product.name %></td>
    <td><%= product.price %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', product %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_product_path(product) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', product, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
    <td><%= link_to "Add to Cart", :controller => 'product', :action => 'add_to_cart' %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

controller

```
 def add_to_cart
    #add my session here
  end
```

I'm not sure what route I should add to make this work. I also have a feeling my link_to line is incorrect.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: post your `routes.rb` or `rake routes`

Comment: Your controller action is spelt as 'add_to_card' whereas link_to is pointing to action 'add_to_cart'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your routes do (assuming you are using a resource route for products) (note the `put`, since you are changing the state):

```
# routes.rb
resources :products do
  member do
    put :add_to_cart
  end
end
```

Then, your link in the view would be:

```
<%= link_to "Add to Cart", add_to_cart_product_path(product), :method => :put %>
```

Also, fix the spelling of the controller action:

```
def add_to_cart
  ...
end
```

Comment: Here are my routes: http://pastie.org/9692381. I'm getting the error No route matches [GET] "/products/1/add_to_cart" when I click the link.